# Crystal Reports summary of a string field

Tags: string, crystal-reports, numbers, summary

I have the following formula named `@newitemQuant`:

```
WhileReadingRecords;
StringVar text := Totext ( {AR_SalesBySalesPersonDenim;1.quantity} , 6 , ""  )  ;  
NumberVar end  := length ( text ) ;
NumberVar clip :=

    (if  Val ( text [ end - 6 to end ] ) = 0 then 1 else 0 ) +
    (if  Val ( text [ end - 5 to end ] ) = 0 then 1 else 0 ) +
    (if  Val ( text [ end - 4 to end ] ) = 0 then 1 else 0 ) +
    (if  Val ( text [ end - 3 to end ] ) = 0 then 1 else 0 ) +
    (if  Val ( text [ end - 2 to end ] ) = 0 then 1 else 0 ) +
    (if  Val ( text [ end - 1 to end ] ) = 0 then 1 else 0 ) +
    (if  Val ( text [ end - 0 to end ] ) = 0 then 1 else 0 )  ;

text [ 1 to Length ( text ) - clip ]
```

This basically converts my database field `{AR_SalesBySalesPersonDenim;1.quantity}` with a NUMBER datatype to STRING before it manipulates with it. And on the report shows the resulting STRING.

Now I want to place a SUMMARY of resulting string field on the report. Can't achieve that.

I have tried using `ToNumber()` within the same formula as well as a new formula:

```
numbervar fVal;
fVal := ToNumber({@newitemQuant}).
```

But no progress. 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: What summary operation do you want on the string field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

Basically to hanlde the number of decimals in your number on the report, just right click the field select Format Object -> Number tab -> in the Decimals formula -> enter

```
If CurrentFieldValue = Int(CurrentFieldValue) Then
0 
else
2
```

Done. Where 2 is the max number of decimals you want to show in anycase.

Thanks

Comment: Thats worked. What a waste of resources my formula would have been. Yours makes it so simple